# CustomView in ListView

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am creating the listview using custom view(image + frameLayout) , but problem is that when i am clicking on the any item on the list view the getView method is called equal to number of items in the ilst view,

I am giving my xmi file here.

```
custon_layout.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Landed" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
           />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/from_user"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="hi"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/from_user_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="hi"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Please Help Me, Thanx in Advance.

Comment: i think you want that if your view have 2 text and one image then only text have different click event and image have different click event . is it ?

Comment: do not use frame layout you can handle this with only linear layout. for code check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

Comment: Your problem is why getView method is being called repeatedly. Am I right?

Comment: @Khawar Raza : yes you are right , have you having solution for that

Comment: Actually its not a problem that getView() is called when you click or scroll the listview. ListView creates its view in this fashion. Suppose you have to create a listview of 100 items. You provide it say an arraylist of 100 objects. Now listview will not create 100 views at once instead it create views while you scroll the listview to make it efficient by saving memory. It just create 10 to 20 views . So when you scroll, it recycles these views.

Answer (score 0):

hello i was changed your xml file of list please check this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:padding="5dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
       />

   <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Landed" 
            android:layout_gravity="center"
           />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/from_user"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="hi"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/from_user_id"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="hi"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

now for list item click [clickhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654)

you can do same click for all list items and you can put different click for different view(mean list items).

its very simple if you have query then comment below.

Comment: @dahval: tahnx but i am trying to slide that linear layout containing two textView and button must be below the linear layout, and it will be visible after the sliding of linear layout is it possible using linearlayoyt

Comment: yes it is possible you have to use VISIBLE for layout and Views. like if you have to invisible button then--> btn.setVisiblity(Button.GONE); and if you wat to show button then btn.setVisiblity(Button.VISIBALE);

Comment: and one more thing now you ask question on stack-overflow. then please add your all needs in question also explain in detail. then you got perfect ans and it may sure help you.