# How to catch onClick on ListView (I don't want onItemClickListener)

Tags: android, listview, adapter, onclicklistener

How to catch `onClick` on `ListView`?

I need to catch the on click event even if there are no items in the list. I tried to put onClickListener on the parent view of the ListView, but the ListView absorbs the event and doesn't let me know.

How can I catch that and process this event?

Please Help Me,

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: check this.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654 and in OnClickListener check size of array if its <= 0 then do notinhg...

Answer (score 1):

one simple and stupid way if you dont want onitemclick

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ListView>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

.

```
 then put onClickListener to ImageView
```

:P

Comment: Cunning plan :):) Will try :)

Comment: Doesn't work. It absorbs the event. Damn. OnTouchListener have problems as well - it either absorbs the event (if you return true) or it doesn't process it (if you return false on the ACTION_DOWN).

Answer (score 0):

Try to create the custom component extending the ListView and override the onclick method.