# Listener not work on list view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

i have list view with listener that works fine , but when i add **android:autoLink:"web"** property at one **textview** in **row.xml** ,List Listener not work. why its so ?
here is row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
   >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ID"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="First" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="56dp"
        android:text="Second" />

    <TextView

          android:autoLink="web"
        android:id="@+id/Link"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ID"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Third" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here is listview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Favourtes"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listforplace"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

here .java class:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bookmark);
        // loadSharedPreferencesforplacelist();
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listforplace);
        myAdapter = new DbManager(this);
        cursor = myAdapter.getAllfav();
        // updateList();
        String[] from = new String[] {/* DbManager.PlaceID, */DbManager.ID,
                DbManager.name, DbManager.referance };
        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.ID, R.id.Name, R.id.Link };
        cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bookmark_row,
                cursor, from, to);

        list.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
        // cursorAdapter.setViewBinder(new ScoreHistoryBinder());
        list.setOnItemClickListener(listOnItemClickListener);

    }

    public ListView.OnItemClickListener listOnItemClickListener = new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            Cursor cursor = (Cursor) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            /* final int */placeidfordelete = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DbManager.ID));
            // int placename =
            // cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbManager.ID));
            placelongi = cursor
                    .getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbManager.name));
            placelati = cursor.getString(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DbManager.referance));
            placealti = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DbManager.des));

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(viewmark.this);
            builder.setTitle("Delete");
            builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);

            builder.setMessage("Delete marks");
            builder.setPositiveButton("Delete",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {

                            myAdapter.delete_byID_place(placeidfordelete);
                            updateList();

                        }
                    });
            builder.setNegativeButton("All delete",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                        }

                    });

            AlertDialog diag = builder.create();
            diag.show();

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() { // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        cursor.close();
        myAdapter.close();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation" })
    private void updateList() {
        cursor.requery();
        cursor.close();
        // //emptyFormFields();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can we have code please ?

Comment: Please post your code ......

Comment: code posted...............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have any clickable views  like Button, ImageButton or anything like that in a row, the onItemClickListener does not work.

**Solution:** You should get the root view of your row in a getView() method of your BaseAdapter and set onClickListener on the rootView.. But in onCLickListener you won't get the position of row which has been clciked.. For getting position you can refer the onClick() method in the getView().

```
            ViewGroup listView = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();

            for(int i=1;i<listView.getChildCount();i++){

                listView.getChildAt(i).equals(v);

                if(listView.getChildAt(i).equals(v)){
                    //"clicked position" = i
                    toAttachmentViewer.putExtra("Name", attachments.get(i-1).getName());
                    toAttachmentViewer.putExtra("MasterId", attachments.get(i-1).getMastedId());
                }
            }
```

Following is the code for whole Adapter class

```
private class AttachmentsListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    List<Attachment> attachments;
    TextView txtHeader;
    TextView txtPdfName;

    public AttachmentsListViewAdapter(List<Attachment> attachments) {

        this.attachments = attachments;
        parentview=new View[this.attachments.size()+1];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return attachments.size()+1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (position==0) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_detail_item_header, null);
            txtHeader=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.header_textView);
            txtHeader.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.attachments));

        } else if (position>0) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.order_attachments_item, null);
            txtPdfName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pdf_textView);
            txtPdfName.setText(attachments.get(position-1).getName());              
        }

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String name,url;
                Intent toAttachmentViewer = new Intent(OrderDetailActivity.this,AttachmentViewerActivity.class);

                if(attachments.get(0).getName()!=null) {

                    name=attachments.get(0).getName();


                } else {

                    name="";
                }

                if(attachments.get(0).getUri()!=null) {

                    url=attachments.get(position-1).getUri();
                } else {

                    url="";
                }

                toAttachmentViewer.putExtra("Name",name);
                toAttachmentViewer.putExtra("URL", url);
                ViewGroup listView = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();

                for(int i=1;i<listView.getChildCount();i++){

                    listView.getChildAt(i).equals(v);

                    if(listView.getChildAt(i).equals(v)){

                        toAttachmentViewer.putExtra("Name", attachments.get(i-1).getName());
                        toAttachmentViewer.putExtra("MasterId", attachments.get(i-1).getMastedId());
                    }
                }
                startActivity(toAttachmentViewer);
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the autoLink web property causes the TextView element to steal click events and prevent them from bubbling up to the ListView.

Answer (score 1):

this is just suggestion :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtViewWeb"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Web: www.pareshnmayani.wordpress.com"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:layout_margin="5dip">
</TextView>
```

check this : http://www.technotalkative.com/android-textview-autolink-attribute/

As per @Berdon answer it is not worked then you have to do it with `CustomAdapter`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

Answer (score 0):

Try to set "android:focusable="false"" on the TextView with autoLink, in order to have the focus on the listitem's rootview and that it then can register the click instead of the textview.

see:
stackoverflow.com/questions/1121192/android-custom-listview-unable-to-click-on-items