# android CustomView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a list obtained after parsing the webservice response. I have created one customview using `BaseAdapter`. The problem I am facing is *I am not able to bind the data to the `ListView`* using the customview I have created. Here is my custom view:

```
public class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    int layoutResourceId;  

    private static List<Item> itemDetailsarrayList;


    private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

    public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, List<Item> results) {
        itemDetailsarrayList = results;
        l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);         
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.txtTitle.setText(itemDetailsarrayList.get(position).getCity_name());
        return convertView;
     }

     static class ViewHolder {   
        TextView txtTitle;
     }
}
```

this is how I am trying to bind:

```
llstCities = Objparsecities.parse();
ItemListBaseAdapter adapter = new ItemListBaseAdapter(this, lstCities);
lstcities = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
lstcities.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: the getCount() always returns 0. That is not good

Comment: sorry Mr Q.C.. i think u might be correct. can you please say me wat i can replace their. since i am new to android and webconsuming.

Answer (score 0):

replace you code with below code : see magic...

```
public class ItemListBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     int layoutResourceId;  

    private static List<Item> itemDetailsarrayList;


    private LayoutInflater l_Inflater;

     public ItemListBaseAdapter(Context context, List<Item> results) {
      itemDetailsarrayList = results;
      l_Inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
     }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemDetailsarrayList.size();


    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ViewHolder holder;
          if (convertView == null) {
           convertView = l_Inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.txtTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);          
           convertView.setTag(holder);
          } else {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
          }

          holder.txtTitle.setText(itemDetailsarrayList.get(position).getCity_name());
          return convertView;
     }

     static class ViewHolder {

         TextView txtTitle;

     }
}
```

Comment: i'm getting the same poblem and wat is the change you have made in you code??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654 check this ans. and can you give me your web services URL?

Comment: thnx for the link:). can i have your email id??.

Comment: Please check my stack profile : http://stackoverflow.com/users/1168654/dhaval-sodha-parmar

Comment: dhaval, this is my response from webservice.

<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <city_ID>1</city_ID>
    <city_name>Bangalore</city_name>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <city_ID>2</city_ID>
    <city_name>Chennai</city_name>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <city_ID>3</city_ID>
    <city_name>Hyderabad</city_name>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>

i have parsed it. 
now i am facing problem in binding to customized listview.

Comment: can you give url of this Webservices??

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at the getCount() method:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return itemDetailsarrayList.size();

}
```

the solution is to return the count of the complete items, the adapter contains.
You should be aware of any methods you have to implement! Not only let eclipse generate the methods. they are only stubs then. If you don't know what to do in the methods, the developer documentation gives you a greate view on that.