# Remove ID of item clicked in list view

Tags: java, android, listview, listitem

```
| Icon(image) |       Title(text)    |  cross(image)  | 
|             |     Description(text)|                |
|             |                      |  coupon(image) |
```

Its a list view.
Here  i want to get id of different items when clicked separately in list view like cross, coupon, icon is clicked then i will get their id...
I'm a newbie...Please help me out....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_iv_icon"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_iv_icon_cross"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"        
    android:src="@drawable/cross_selector" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_tv_title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_item_iv_icon"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#CC0033"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_tv_desc"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list_item_tv_title"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/list_item_iv_icon"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:textColor="#3399FF"
    android:textIsSelectable="false"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_iv_type"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/list_item_iv_icon"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I know how to get id of the clicked list. i want to know is how to get item id of a clicked item in list.

Comment: I don't see any `ListView` in the xml + http://whathaveyoutried.com?

Comment: its the list items. which  i'm implementing in listview.

Comment: check this link it may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

Comment: You have to write onclicklistener for each item. That is the only solution as far as i know.

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar its perfect example and thankyou very much. but there's a little problem my adapter class is different and the class in which i'm implementing is diff. So how can i do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer for NewBies like Me...

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/list_item_iv_icon_cross"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"        
    android:src="@drawable/cross_selector"
    android:onClick="onCrossClick" />
```

i used onClick on item and to get position in which it has been clicked i used

```
final int position = listView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
```

full code :-

```
public void onCrossClick(View v) {

    final int position = listView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
    Toast.makeText(this, "click on button " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
            .show();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the code to set a listener for the list view which would capture the list item selection event.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // To get the item from the list use the position value
            Object yourObject = yourAdapter.getItem(position);                                
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Check below Sample code :

```
public class ListViewAdapter_test extends BaseAdapter {

            private LayoutInflater mInflater;

            public ListViewAdapter_test(Context con) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);
            }

            public int getCount() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return a_product_id.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // return product_id1.size();
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // return product_id1.get(position).hashCode();
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final ListContent holder;
                View v = convertView;
                if (v == null) {
                    v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.scan_row1, null);
                    holder = new ListContent();

                    holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sc_textname);

                    holder.name1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.sc_review);

                    holder.ratings = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.sc_ratingBar1);

                    holder.total_rate = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button1);

                    holder.img_p = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.image_prod);

                    // holder.total_rate.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener1);


                    v.setTag(holder);
                } else {

                    holder = (ListContent) v.getTag();
                }


                holder.total_rate.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener3);

                holder.img_p.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener_image);

                return v;
            }
        }

        static class ListContent {

            ImageView img_p;
            TextView name1;
            TextView name;
            RatingBar ratings;
            Button total_rate;

        }

        public OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener3 = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int position = list_v
                        .getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());

                Log.d("you are click on Ratings","you are click on Ratings");

            }
        };

            public OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener_image = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int position = list_v
                        .getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());

                Log.d("you are click on image view","you are click on image view");


            }
        };
```