# How To Get which button or image is clicked in the listview android?

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

you can check it in image i have 2 view in listview left side imageview and right side buttonview other is textview but i have to call different activity when imageview call is start another activity and if is click on button than is called different activity so how can i get the particular button or image clicke event in listview

Activity Class.java

```
liststipciations.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long l) {


    Log.e("list stipcitaions", "-->"+liststipciations.getItemIdAtPosition(position));



    }
});
```

Adapter Class.java

```
public class LazyAdapterStipciationsAdvertise extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    private static final String TAG_SHOWTEXT="showtext";
    String showtext;

    private static final String TAG_PRODUCTINFO="product_info";
    String productinfo;

    private static final String TAG_THUMBIMAGE="thumbsrc";
    String thumbimage;

    private static final String TAG_STIPCIATED="stipciated";
    String stipciated;

    private static final String TAG_DISTANCE="distance";
    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result; 
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public GridImageLoader gridimageLoader; 
    int imageWidth;
    int imageheight;
    Context context; 
    int width;
    int height;

    int layoutwidth;
    int layoutheight;

    public LazyAdapterStipciationsAdvertise(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> r)
    {
        activity = a;
        result=r;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        gridimageLoader=new GridImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

        width = a.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        height=a.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        imageWidth = ((width*18)/100);
        layoutheight=((height*20)/100);



    }

    public int getCount() {
        return result.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView textpromotional;
        public TextView textdistance;
        public ImageView imageadvertise;
        public ImageView imagestipciate;
        public ImageView imagestipciated;

    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View vi=convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stipciationslist, null);
             holder=new ViewHolder();
            holder.textpromotional=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textpromotional);
            holder.textdistance=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.textdistance);
            holder.imageadvertise=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageadvertise);
            holder.imageadvertise.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth,imageWidth));

            holder.imagestipciate=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imagestipciate);
            holder.imagestipciated=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imagestipciated);
            vi.setTag(holder);
        }
        else

            holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();


        holder.textpromotional.setText(result.get(position).get(TAG_SHOWTEXT));
        holder.textdistance.setText(result.get(position).get(TAG_DISTANCE));
        holder.imageadvertise.setTag(result.get(position).get(TAG_THUMBIMAGE));
        holder.imageadvertise.setId(1);

        if(result.get(position).get(TAG_STIPCIATED).equals("1"))
        {
            holder.imagestipciated.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imagestipciated.setId(2);
            holder.imagestipciate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        if(result.get(position).get(TAG_STIPCIATED).equals("0"))
        {
            holder.imagestipciate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.imagestipciate.setId(3);
            holder.imagestipciated.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        gridimageLoader.DisplayImage(result.get(position).get(TAG_THUMBIMAGE), activity, holder.imageadvertise);
        return vi;
    }

    public static float convertDpToPixel(float dp, Context context){
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = resources.getDisplayMetrics();
        float px = dp * (metrics.densityDpi/160f);
        return px;
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Write OnClicklisteners for Imageview and Button in the adapter's getView() method. and use intent to start required activities. Note: you need to pass context while setting the adapter.

Comment: Check out this link. i had same prob but its solved now. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290360/i-want-to-get-id-of-item-clicked-in-list-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement `setOnClickListener` for button as well as for image in `getView` method. Hope below code will help you.

```
Button myButton

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    myButton = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.myButton);

    myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, OtherActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```