# How could i pass the value from base adapter to activity

Tags: android, android-activity, baseadapter

I am working in one app where i need to pass the value from base adapter class to activity

here is the snippet code:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


            vi=convertView;


            if(convertView==null){
                vi = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.screen, null);

               position_pin = position;

              Holder.images=(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
              Holder.textview=(TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);



             Holder.images.setImageResource(imageIds[position]);
           Holder.text.setText(name);//here name is String 

             vi.setTag(Holder);   

            }

                        return vi;
            }
```

Here i am getting the image id position:

```
 Holder.images.setImageResource(imageIds[position]);
```

**how could i pass the imageIds position to activity** Thanks !!

Comment: this base adapter is for spinner or listview or anything else...?

Comment: @nidhi_adiga its listview

Comment: @nidhi_adiga an you help me!!

Comment: Idon't know if its soln but u can store the positions in a global array and then u can access it in ur activity right...

Comment: @nidhi_adiga I have tried that but i did not get ,is it possible to get the position!!!

Comment: yes but not before u call setAdapter method to listview is called bcoz then only ur getView method gets called...

Comment: i have called  listview.setAdapter(adapter);method ..

Comment: @nidhi_adiga how to pass the position from adapter class to activity?

Comment: Can't u use OnItemClickListener for ur listview so that u get clicked items position there...

Comment: No that is the problem is there no other way!!

Comment: If there is a way also I don't know. I am sorry that i wasted ur time good luck...

Comment: Hey positions r like 0 1 2 3 ... so on right so u can get count of no of items in listview then u can use that in for loop...

Comment: @nidhi_adiga yes.like that brief explanation will be fine

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

Comment: you get total listview size from imageIds.size(); brcoz you list view is made by some array. so your array size is you listview item size.

Comment: yes..but in listview which image is displaying that i need to know na

Comment: i ll give you code wait..

Comment: you can use interface............

Answer (score -1):

U  can use below code inside ur activity

```
 for(int i=0;i<list.getCount();i++)
  {
   //here u can add i values to an array for storing positions or do anything else u want
  }
```

Comment: Hey he wants to do this in image click or list item click... whats your code does??

Comment: Read the comments above she said she can't use on item click