# pass the item id from baseadapter

Tags: android, android-activity, baseadapter

here i got a simple issue regarding my code,how could i get the item id from base adapter

here i called the adapter from the activity:

```
adapter = new sampleadapter(screen.this,imageIds);

      listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The adapter class:

```
public class  sampleadapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public sampleadapter(screen ListViewActivity,int[] imageIds) {
                // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            }

            public int getCount() {
                return imageIds.length;
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }


        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


                vi=convertView;


               vi = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.explorescreen, null);


                  Holder.images=(ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.image);


                 Holder.images.setImageResource(imageIds[position]);


                 vi.setTag(ViewHolder);   

                      Holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();




                        return vi;
            }


        };
```

here :

I need to pass the value of `imageIds[position]` to my activity how could i do that?

could anybody help me out ,@Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: you want to know how to pass value from 1 activity to another/

Comment: if u want to pass value on listView row click then set OnItemClickListner for ListView and start another Activity using intent

Comment: mListView.getAdapter().getItemId(position);

Comment: Just go through some tutorials about ListView...Because your shows that you need to learn a lot..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15565310/how-could-i-pass-the-value-from-base-adapter-to-activity. duplicate by same user

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK no its like i am getting images on scrolling based on imageIds[position] i need to pass the same position to the same activity

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic yes i know by using onitemclick listener but..here the scenario is different

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar here i need to pass which image did i scroll based on that position i need to get the data

Comment: @Raghunandan that question also asked by me ,as i did not get the answer i have asked again!!

Comment: @priya2134412. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty. Check the link

Comment: @Raghunandan  i dont have enough point for bounty but if you will give the answer sure i will upvote and accept your answer

Comment: @priya2134412 : instead of getting value in Main Activity you can pass View which u want to update with imageIds[position] using sampleadapter constructor

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK its fine..but that will be different then text will also come in listview, i need that the text should be fixed in that location based on images the text title should change!!is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this interface to your adapter class:

```
public interface MyItemFoundListener{
public void itemFound(int resourceId);
}
```

make a variable in you adapter class

```
MyItemFoundListener mItemFoundListener;
```

add a method to your adapter class

```
public void setOnMyItemFoundListener(MyItemFoundListener listener)
{
    mItemFoundListener = listener;
}
```

in getView method put

```
if(mItemFoundListener!=null)
    mItemFoundListener.itemFound(imageIds[position]);
```

Now implement the Interface in your Activity class

```
MyActivity implements MyItemFoundListener
```

after `adapter = new sampleadapter(screen.this,imageIds);`
add `adapter.setOnMyItemFoundListener(this);`

add this method to your Activity class

```
public void itemFound(int resourceId){
//Now whenever getView from adapter will be called it will pass the resourceId here in your activity
}
```

Comment: This exactly what you need.

Comment: Naveen yes..when i will scroll the image i will get some id based on that text will set

Comment: Have you implemented this solution?

Comment: sorry its not working

Comment: do you have any better options...@Naveen

Comment: You can add your adapter class in your Activity Class itself and just call a method of your activity directly from the getView of Adapter.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26714/discussion-between-naveen-and-priya2134412)

Comment: The first answer at 9:38 worked perfectly! It is a very elegant way of passing data back to the activity, without using messy intents. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Your getItem and getItemID methods are incorrect.

GetItem should return an array member. Not an array index.

GetItemID should use getitem, then return the ID via the getter of the member returned.

You will also need to implement hasStableIDs to return true on your adapter.

The object id will then be returned for you by any setItemClickListener implementations attached to listviews that use your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

in your adapter getView() method add this line:

```
holder.img_p.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener_image);
```

in you class put this code :

```
public OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener_image = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int position = listv.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());

            Intent i = new Intent(Activity.this, nextactivity.class);
            i.putExtra("position",""+position);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    };
```

in your next Activity in onCreate():

```
String extras = getIntent().getStringExtra("position");
```

above code is for only image you can create many for diffrent view for more detail refer this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

your next Activity

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                String extras = getIntent().getStringExtra("position");
// your position is below
                int pos = Integet.parseInteget(extras);
                Log.e("position-->",""+pos);
// now you can use this position any where in your class

  }

}
```

Comment: i have edited my question @Dhaval Sodha Parmar

Comment: i have give you code wich you acxectly want.

Comment: using you code i will get the position right how could i use that in activity

Comment: check my edited ans.....

Comment: i am not passing to another activity in the same activity i need the data from based adapter

Comment: ohhooooo then just put global variable and get value from mOnTitleClickListener_image. i hope you have knoladge of variables in JAVA

Comment: you mean global variable to position ..its showing nullpointer exception

Comment: i want to check you all Activity code. can you post it in question????

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26713/discussion-between-dhaval-sodha-parmar-and-priya2134412)