# Click on ListView Item not working, I have three textviews and a button in my each ListView Item

Tags: android, android-listview

I am writing an app in which i am trying *to open an activity and update item detail* using **Tap on Item in a ListView**

**Problem:**

whenever i do click on item in a ListView, not able to start that activity and i also want to know how to update item detail...

**I have three textviews and a button in my each ListView Item**

*By using below code in CartActivity, i am not able to open ProductInformationActivity*

```
    ListView mLstView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    CartAdapter mViewCartAdpt = new CartAdapter(CartActivity.this);
mLstView1.setAdapter(mViewCartAdpt);
    mLstView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(CartActivity.this, com.ProductInformationActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

CartAdapter.java:

```
  public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
    item = Constants.mItem_Detail.get(position);

    // Setting all values in listview

    title.setText(item.get(com.ProductInformationActivity.KEY_TITLE));
    qty.setText(item.get(com.ProductInformationActivity.KEY_QTY));
    cost.setText(item.get(com.ProductInformationActivity.KEY_COST));
    total.setText(item.get(com.ProductInformationActivity.KEY_TOTAL));

    return vi;

}
```

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar no errors and no click respond as well buddy

Comment: try to create click listner in adapter getview method check this ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

Comment: @DhavalSodhaParmar yeah i guess you are right so could you please show me some code to open an activity while click on any of the item in a listview and i also want to update my product detail

Comment: @SuriAmit please can you past your XML of listVIew and listrow_cart.xml

Comment: @SuriAmit: check my ans: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15833490/1168654

Answer (score 0):

Have you added your Ativity to your manifest File?
You need to add your activity in the application tag:

```
<activity android:name="com.erachnida.restaurant.versionoct.menu.ProductInformationActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you are assigned <kbd>OnItemClickListener</kbd> for whole ListView and then for ImageView. Also about ImageView, look:

```
Intent mInViewCartRefresh = new Intent(activity, CartActivity.class);
activity.startActivity(mInViewCartRefresh);
activity.finish();
```

Here you are probably trying to "refresh" ListView but this is wrong. If you want to update your ListView all what you need is to use

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

that indicates that: *"I changed datasource, i want from your refresh yourself."*

So my suggestion is to remove your "inner" listener, remove your snippet of code mentioned above and leave only your listener for ListView.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CartActivity.this, ProductInformationActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then if you click on ListView, from **int position** parameter you can get particular item for collection and you can do whatever you want with it. After "action" you need to call notifyDataSetChanged() that refresh your ListView.

Comment: i just want to open CartActivity.java don't want to refresh my ListView

Comment: @SuriAmit why CartActivity? in CartActivity you have your ListView, isnt?

Answer (score 0):

Asper our conversation you have check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654).  so, in `itemClickListener` put this lines:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CartActivity.this, ProductInformationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
```

just like below:

```
public OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener3 = new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int position = list_v
                        .getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());

                Log.d("you are click on Ratings","you are click on Ratings");
                Intent intent = new Intent(CartActivity.this, ProductInformationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        };
```