# Layout Problems in Listview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have problem design wise. I am looking to display two pictures hortizontally inside of one row in a listView. like this:

```
  TextView
  ImageView
  ImageView
```

I am looking to see if i can use just an xml or do i have to consider using a different view altogether. I have Listview and a custom row xml through a baseadapter. see code for details

```
    public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


        private Integer[] imgid = {
                R.drawable.up2,
                R.drawable.up3,
                R.drawable.up4,
                R.drawable.up5,
                R.drawable.up6,
                R.drawable.up7,
                R.drawable.up8,
                R.drawable.up9,
                R.drawable.down2,
                R.drawable.down3,
                R.drawable.down4,
                R.drawable.down5,
                R.drawable.down6,
                R.drawable.down7,
                R.drawable.down8,
                R.drawable.down9 };


        private static ArrayList<DisplayResults> searchArrayList;

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, List<DisplayResults> list) {
            searchArrayList = (ArrayList<DisplayResults>) list;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return searchArrayList.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return searchArrayList.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                //holder.txtName = (TextView)                         `     

                        convertView.findViewById(R.id.ServiceName);
                holder.imgPhoto = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Up);

                //holder.imgPhoto2= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Down);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            //holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getName());      

      holder.imgPhoto.setImageResource(imgid[searchArrayList.get(position).getImageNumber()]);
            System.out.println(searchArrayList.get(position).getImageNumber());
            //holder.imgPhoto2.setImageResource(imgid[searchArrayList.get(position).getImageNumber2()]);

            return convertView;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtName;
            ImageView imgPhoto;
            //ImageView imgPhoto2;
        }
    }



    public class satDataFrag extends Fragment {

    Data datas;

    ListView listView;
    LayoutInflater inflaterT;


    public satDataFrag(Data data)
    {
        this.datas=data;
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {   
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sat, container, false);
        inflaterT = inflater;
        listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listSat);

        //ImageView imgView;
        //imgView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        List<DisplayResults> List =  new ArrayList<DisplayResults>();

        DisplayResults temp= new DisplayResults();
        for(int i=0; i<datas.features.size(); i++)
        {

        if(datas.features.get(i).attributes.ServiceTyp.equalsIgnoreCase("Satellite"))
            {
                temp.setName(datas.features.get(i).attributes.dbANAME);

    temp.setImageNumber(upKey(datas.features.get(i).attributes.maxADUP));
    temp.setImageNumber2(downKey(datas.features.get(i).attributes.maxADDOWN));
                List.add(temp);
            }
        }

        //ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(getActivity(),
            //    R.layout.list_row, List);

        listView.setAdapter(new MyCustomBaseAdapter(getActivity(), List)); 
        return view;    

        }

    public Integer upKey (String max)
    {

        if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("3"))
        {
            return  1;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
        {
            return 2;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("5"))
        {
            return  3;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("6"))
        {
            return  4;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("7"))
        {
            return  5;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("8"))
        {
            return  6;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("9"))
        {
            return  7;
        }
        else 
        {
            return 7;
        }

    }

    public Integer downKey (String max)
    {

        if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("2"))
        {
            return 8;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("3"))
        {
            return  9;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("4"))
        {
            return 10;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("5"))
        {
            return  11;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("6"))
        {
            return  12;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("7"))
        {
            return  13;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("8"))
        {
            return  14;
        }
        else if(max.equalsIgnoreCase("9"))
        {
            return  15;
        }
        else 
        {
            return 7;
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
    custom_row.xml
```

---

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">    

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/ServiceName"
    android:text=""/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Up"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        />

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/Down"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

So my question is: Is there a way to display two images and a text in one row inside a listview??

Comment: Not an error but more of a problem. when the code is run. I only see the text. when i delete the text entry from the xml i can see the first picture, and when i delete the first picture etc... I need a row big enough to view all of it

Comment: can you elaborate your question.

Comment: I have elabroted. Basically how do i get two images and text in one row inside a listview

Comment: get idea from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer that I created!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ServiceName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Down"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="left">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/Up"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have provided your XML, I can see that **TextView** and **ImageView** has **width** to "match_parent". So remove that code and replace with following one.

I am providing "wrap_content" to TextView. This will give space to TextView what it wants after rendering. And ImageView has provided "100dp" width, so they will not exceed it, because may be images are large and if we make them "wrap_content", they occupy full width and height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/ServiceName"
        android:text=""/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Up"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/Down"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

There is also another option available, "weight".

You can provide **weight** to your views' inside linear layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/ServiceName"
        android:text=""/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Up"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/Down"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```