# Select an item inside listview adapter android

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, onitemclicklistener

In my main activity i called an object write a method itemClicked().

```
public void itemClicked(){

        System.out.println("Clicked");
        efficienadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

I am trying to print Clicked item when i select a row from my listview. Note: I am using a listadapter called EfficientAdapter.

Here is the adapter:

```
     public class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {



            private Activity activity;
            private ArrayList<ComptePost> data;
            private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
            public ImageLoader imageLoader; 
            public  Boolean isActusAstuce;
            public static int flag = 0, counter=0;
            NVirementEmmeteur main;
            int num=0;

            ViewHolder holder;
            static String src;

            public EfficientAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<ComptePost> d) {


                activity = a;
                data = d;
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //  imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
                imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
            }

            public EfficientAdapter(NVirementEmmeteur m) {
                main=m;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return data.toArray().length;

            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {

                return position;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public static class ViewHolder {

                public TextView one;
                public TextView two;
                public TextView three;
                public ImageView image;
                        public RelativeLayout relative;
            }

            @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View vi = convertView;



                if (convertView == null) {

                    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_item, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.one = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text_view_one);
                    holder.image = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
                    holder.relative = (Relativelayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.relative);
vi.setTag(holder);

                } else
                    holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();

                    holder.one.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                    holder.one.setText("Compte No."+data.get(position).getNumComtpe());
                    holder.image.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                    holder.relative_layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    main.itemClicked();

                }

            });


                    //flag=0; only first row become white


                return vi;
            }


i used main.itemClicked() to print "Clicked". 


        holder.relative_layout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    main.itemClicked();

                }

            });
```

but when i select a row item i got this error.

```
04-10 14:21:43.832: W/dalvikvm(4985): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015578)
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985):     at .EfficientAdapter$1.onClick(EfficientAdapter.java:111)
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2538)
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9152)
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
04-10 14:21:43.847: E/AndroidRuntime(4985):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

where am i mistaken ?

Comment: not what i am looking for :(

Comment: nope i think my constructor is the guilty " NVirementEmmeteur main;"

Comment: you have add click listnet on vi mean on convertView insted of use itemclick for difftent item like i given above or use perent layout click which is in  R.layout.single_item. if you have linear layout then use linearlayout.onitemclick....

Comment: can you give me an example i don't get it

Comment: you have checked this----> http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654 if yes then i have added holder.button.setOnClickListener for each item of list. in your code you are tring to click on view which is vi in your code. insted of that put item click in LinearLayout whih is in row file in my example same way you have to do that..

Comment: yes i use holder.relative which is a  RelativeLayout but the null pointer is still here

Comment: its updated take a look at it

Comment: thank you i finally get it with you example :)

Comment: no i want to show imageView1 when user select a row

Comment: yes but when i tried to set the image visible from the onclicklistener  it crashed i mean this v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: Now i did this it receive set the image to visible but only the first and last two images in row    EfficientAdapter.ViewHolder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: i found your solution.. wait i ll add as answer..

Comment: ok dude i'll mark your answer

Comment: check my ans-----> http://stackoverflow.com/a/15925420/1168654

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**here is simple example how to hide image from list view. first try to understand this code after that modify your code.**

[image]

i have listview with text & image.

here is row file of list view `my_spinner_style.xml`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

my activity class:

```
package com.example.testapp;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[] { "Belgium",
            "France", "Italy" };

    private static final Integer[] img = new Integer[] {
            R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.dhaval1, R.drawable.ic_launcher };

    private MyArrayAdapter adapter;
    Bundle savedInstanceState;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this);
        getListView().setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private class MyArrayAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MyArrayAdapter(Context con) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(con);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return COUNTRIES.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final ListContent holder;
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_spinner_style, null);
                holder = new ListContent();

                holder.name = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

                holder.name2 = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

                v.setTag(holder);
            } else {

                holder = (ListContent) v.getTag();
            }

            holder.name.setText("" + Html.fromHtml("" + COUNTRIES[position]));

            holder.name2.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                    img[position]));
            holder.name.setOnClickListener(mOnTitleClickListener3);

            return v;
        }

    }

    static class ListContent {

        TextView name;

        ImageView name2;

    }

    public OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener3 = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int position = getListView().getPositionForView(
                    (View) v.getParent());

            View rowView = getListView().getChildAt(position);
            if (rowView != null) { // do whatever you want here
                View mainv = ((ViewGroup) rowView).getChildAt(1);
                Log.e("select dd--->", "" + mainv);

                // hide Image from here....
                mainv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
    };

    protected void onRestart() {
        // adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    };

}
```

**I have addd `OnClickListener` on `TextView` insted of that you can use your perent layout. im my case is `LinearLayout`.**

Comment: i use this in my main activity  public static OnClickListener compte_emmetteur_clicked = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int position = lv1.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());            
            
   EfficientAdapter.ViewHolder.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   image_compte_emmeteur.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.virement_compte_emmeteur_gris);

            Log.d("you are click on Ratings", PostList.get(position).getNumComtpe());

        }
    };

Comment: i want to adapt the first example to my code not change everything dude. i come to a good path with the first example you give. just need to know how to set the image to visible for a selected row. but i'll mark your answer as the right answer as you help me a lot

Comment: @yakusha: this type of stuff is not working well.. just for k'no prepose i have added this here.. but i don't saggest any one to do like this...

Comment: yes but it gave is a solution and give me expected result for some situation

Answer (score 1):

In this case, shouldn't you use setOnItemClickListener? If yes, put it in your ListView.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        MainActivity.itemClicked();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i suspect that this is happening here:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println("Clicked "+data.get(position).getDebitMin());
    v.findViewById(R.id.imageView1).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    main.itemClicked();
}
```

the error is happening in line 111, this means that one of three options happened:
 1. data is `null` or data.`getposition` is `null`.
 2. the view you are finding in the next line is returning `null`.
 3. main is `null`.

Comment: but how can item clicked be null if i am just printing a default value. is it my constructor which is wrong :O

Comment: you're passing `null` in the constructor.

Comment: if you're calling the first constructor, you should create a `NVirementEmmeteur`, since you're not doing this, I assume you should have a line with some sort of `main = new NVirementEmmeteur()`

Comment: ow i ommitted this line :O it works now thanks you thepoosh everything is ok now :) thanks to you