# Determining which inflated item is click

Tags: android

I have this view:

`list.xml`

```
<LinearLayout>
   <ImageView />
   <TextView />
   <TextView />
</LinearLayout>
```

inflated into this view:

`main.xml`

```
<HorizontalScrollView>
    <LinearLayout/>
</HoriztontalScrollView>
```

The data is from a json and is dynamic.

```
    try{
        products = jsonObj.getJSONArray(Constants.PRODUCT_ARR);

        if(products.length() != 0){
            for(int i = 0; i < products.length(); i++){
                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                String sName = c.getString(Constants.SHOP_NAME);
                String productId = c.getString(Constants.SHOP_ID);
                String desc = c.getString(Constants.SHOP_DESC);
                String imageUrl = c.get(Constants.SHOP_IMAGE_URL) == JSONObject.NULL ? null : c.getString(Constants.PRODUCT_IMAGE_URL);
                String imgWidth = c.get(Constants.IMAGE_WIDTH) == JSONObject.NULL ? null : c.getString(Constants.IMAGE_WIDTH);
                String imgHeight = c.get(Constants.IMAGE_HEIGHT) == JSONObject.NULL ? null : c.getString(Constants.IMAGE_HEIGHT);
                String productOwnerId = c.getString(Constants.SHOP_OWNER_ID);

                if(imgHeight != null && imgWidth != null && imageUrl != null){
                    product = new ProductRowItem(imageUrl, sName, productId, desc, Integer.parseInt(imgHeight), Integer.parseInt(imgWidth), productOwnerId);
                    productItems.add(product);
                }
            }
        }else{
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"SHOP NULL",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.show();
        }

    }catch(JSONException e){
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

I then inflate `list.xml` to `main.xml`.

```
    final ProductBaseAdapter adapter = new ProductBaseAdapter(context, productItems);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_temp);


    for(int i = 0 ; i < adapter.getCount() ; i++){
        View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
        layout.addView(item);
        item.setTag("test"+i);
    }
```

But, how can have an OnClickListener for each item? Because clicking each item will start a new activity which contains the detailed information of each `product`. My problem is on how to identify which item is clicked and how to listen for the onclick. I've know about `setTag()` and `getTag()` but I was confuse on how to implement these. My plan was to use product ID as a parameter for my `setTag` so that I'll just have to get that Tag to identify which product is clicked. But I'm still trying to figure this out. But for the time being, can anyone shed light on this, as to how/ where to put my method for onclicklistener and how to determine which product is clicked?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16164976/1770916 is the solution of this. setOnClick listerners in `getView`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this:-

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < adapter.getCount() ; i++){
    View item = adapter.getView(i, null, null);
    item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {
                //Call your details activity here.
              }
           });
    layout.addView(item);
    item.setTag("test"+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use some unique identification such as position (using this first check which position you have clicked ) . You are using product items to add all the elements which you have downloaded from the web service. it should be Array list or array. So using your clicked position you can access the data from your stored array list or array. so from this you can come to know which item you have clicked.  hope this will help you.

To know more about accessing the settag and get tag follow this tutorial .
http://amitandroid.blogspot.in/2013/03/android-listview-with-checkbox-and.html

hope this will help you.