# Android Adding OnClickListener to listview

Tags: android

I have been trying to create a settings app for my new rom called "ProtoType" and i am trying to add an OnClickListener to my listview but i cant find the appropriate way to do so and as a result i have turned to here for help and i was wondering if anybody can show me how i'll post my activity below and thanks.

```
package fr.xgouchet.tuto.switchpreferences;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

public class MyPrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private List<Header> mHeaders;

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setTitle("Settings"); 

        if (getListAdapter() instanceof MyPrefsHeaderAdapter)
            ((MyPrefsHeaderAdapter) getListAdapter()).resume();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (getListAdapter() instanceof MyPrefsHeaderAdapter)
            ((MyPrefsHeaderAdapter) getListAdapter()).pause();
    }

    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        // Called when the settings screen is up for the first time
        // we load the headers from our xml description

        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.my_prefs_headers, target);

        mHeaders = target;
    }

    public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        int i, count;

        if (mHeaders == null) {
            mHeaders = new ArrayList<Header>();
            // When the saved state provides the list of headers,
            // onBuildHeaders is not called
            // so we build it from the adapter given, then use our own adapter

            count = adapter.getCount();
            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                mHeaders.add((Header) adapter.getItem(i));
        }

        super.setListAdapter(new MyPrefsHeaderAdapter(this, mHeaders));
    }
}
```

Comment: did you checked onItemClickListener for listView

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On PreferenceActivity listView is hiddent behind getListView();
**The simpliest example:**

```
ListView listView = getListView();
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int i, long l) {
            Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "myPos "+i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

**Code will look like**

```
package fr.xgouchet.tuto.switchpreferences;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;

public class MyPrefsActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private List<Header> mHeaders;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  



        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View view, int i, long l) {
                Toast.makeText(Activity.this, "myPos "+i, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
     }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        setTitle("Settings"); 

        if (getListAdapter() instanceof MyPrefsHeaderAdapter)
            ((MyPrefsHeaderAdapter) getListAdapter()).resume();
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (getListAdapter() instanceof MyPrefsHeaderAdapter)
            ((MyPrefsHeaderAdapter) getListAdapter()).pause();
    }

    public void onBuildHeaders(List<Header> target) {
        // Called when the settings screen is up for the first time
        // we load the headers from our xml description

        loadHeadersFromResource(R.xml.my_prefs_headers, target);

        mHeaders = target;
    }

    public void setListAdapter(ListAdapter adapter) {
        int i, count;


        if (mHeaders == null) {
            mHeaders = new ArrayList<Header>();
            // When the saved state provides the list of headers,
            // onBuildHeaders is not called
            // so we build it from the adapter given, then use our own adapter

            count = adapter.getCount();
            for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                mHeaders.add((Header) adapter.getItem(i));
        }

        super.setListAdapter(new MyPrefsHeaderAdapter(this, mHeaders));
    }

}
```

Comment: I suggest in public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

Comment: but exactly where becuase i get a bunch i red underlines

Comment: can you put it into my code becuase i dont have an oncreate  like their is above

Comment: It tells me to add unimplemented methods to fix the red underling here-->AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()

Comment: Instead of `getListView()` you can also use `ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);` (if name of the listview is `listView`). And instead of `Activity.this` you can also use `getBaseContext()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be implemented in your adapter. This is example of a custom adapter. You can specify settings and listeners for elements in items.

```
/** Provides the custom adapter for views of words */
private class WordAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<DTOWord> {
    Context context;
    int layoutResourceId;
    ArrayList<DTOWord> wordsArray;

    /** Set up words data */
    public WordAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, 
            ArrayList<DTOWord> words) 
    {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, words);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.wordsArray = words;            
    }

    @Override
    /** Returns a view with a word */
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        View row = convertView;

        if (row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).
                    getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        }

        return this.getView(row, this.wordsArray.get(position));
    }

    /** Set up the view of the word with specified data */
    private View getView(View wordView, final DTOWord wordData)
    {
        View container = (View) wordView.findViewById(R.id.
                layout_wordData);
        TextView title = (TextView) wordView.findViewById(R.id.
                textView_word);
        Button btnEditWord = (Button) wordView.findViewById(R.id.
                btn_wordEdit);

        this.setEditListener(btnEditWord, wordData);            

        return wordView;
    }

    /** Set action which switches to the edition view of the selected word */
    private void setEditListener(Button btnEditWord, final DTOWord wordData) {
        btnEditWord.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(WordAdapter.this.context, 
                        AddWord.class);
                i.putExtra("word-name", wordData.getWord());
                i.putExtra("word-language", wordData.getLanguage().
                        getName());
                startActivity(i);           
            }
        });
    }
}
```