# Showing Last List Item value in a Dialog not exact row's which i have clicked

Tags: android, android-listview

How to show exact value of list item in a dialog by using click on a Button

In above image we have first list item with name of IMG_20130626_095144.jpg and last record with name of IMG_20130626_095154.jpg

and here i have clicked on first row's upload button, but getting last row value in Dialog, please tell me where i am missing?

**Activity:**

```
    // Get File Name
    fileName = strPath.substring(strPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, strPath.length());                 
        }
```

Comment: take idea from here... http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code check it and reply me if we have done

```
public class OldUploadActivity extends Activity  {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "OldUploadActivity";
    private ListView lstView;
    Bundle bundle;
    String keytitle;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();;

    List <String> ImageList;

    String fileName;

//        created by farrukh
    String selectedFileName;



    TextView txtName ;
    File file;
    String name;

    String strPath;
    String strSDPath;

    final private static int DIALOG_LOGIN = 1;
    EditText file_name, image_name, person_name, person_email ;       

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);       
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_uploads);

         // Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
                }

        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        keytitle = bundle.getString("KEY");

        /*** Get Images from SDCard ***/
        ImageList = getSD();

        // ListView and imageAdapter
        lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        lstView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    }


    private List <String> getSD()
    {
        List <String> it = new ArrayList <String>();            
        String string = "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Images/";
        File f = new File (string+ keytitle+ "/");          
        File[] files = f.listFiles ();          
        for (int i = 0; i <files.length; i++)           
        {
            File  file = files[i];              
            it.add (file.getPath());
        }           
        return it;
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Context context;

        public ImageAdapter(Context c)
        {
            context = c;
        }
        public int getCount() {
            return ImageList.size();
        }
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_column, null);
            }
            // ColImgName
            txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgName);
            Log.d("OldUploadActivity", "txtName" + txtName);
            strPath = ImageList.get(position).toString();
            Log.d("OldUploadActivity", "strPath" + strPath);
            name = txtName.getText().toString();

            // Get File Name
            fileName = strPath.substring(strPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, strPath.length());

            Log.d("OldUploadActivity", "fileName" + fileName);
            file = new File(strPath);
            Log.d("OldUploadActivity", "file" + file);
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            long length = file.length();
            txtName.setPadding(3, 0, 0, 0);
            txtName.setText(fileName);

            // txtName.setText(fileName + " ("+length/1024+" KB.)");

            // Image Resource
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColImgPath);
            imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 110;
            imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 110;
            imageView.setPadding(10, 10, 2, 10);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(strPath);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);


            //  ColStatus
            final TextView txtStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
            txtStatus.setPadding(3, 0, 0, 0);
            txtStatus.setText("...");

            // progressBar
            final ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) convertView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
            progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            progress.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

            //  btnUpload
            final Button btnUpload = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
            btnUpload.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                // Upload
                //Created by farrukh
                selectedFileName=ImageList.get(position).toString().substring(strPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, strPath.length());
                showDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN);
                }
            });     

            //  btnPrint
            final Button btnPrint = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnPrint);
            btnPrint.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            btnPrint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Print
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Print Image via Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }); 

            return convertView;             
        }
    }
    @Override   
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {

        AlertDialog dialogDetails = null;
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_LOGIN:
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
            View dialogview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder dialogbuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialogbuilder.setTitle("Image Information");
            dialogbuilder.setView(dialogview);
            dialogDetails = dialogbuilder.create();
            break;  
        }
        return dialogDetails;
    }

@Override

    protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_LOGIN:
        final AlertDialog alertDialog = (AlertDialog) dialog;
            Button loginbutton = (Button) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
            Button cancelbutton = (Button) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.btn_cancel);
            file_name = (EditText) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.edit_file_name);
            /*image_name = (EditText) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.edit_image_name);
            person_name = (EditText) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.edit_person_name);
            person_email = (EditText) alertDialog
                    .findViewById(R.id.edit_person_email);*/

            file_name.setText(selectedFileName);                

            loginbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    SaveData();     
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                }

                private boolean SaveData() {

                    final AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(OldUploadActivity.this);

                    ad.setTitle("Error! ");
                    ad.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                    ad.setPositiveButton("Close", null);

                    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/res/uploadImage.php";             

                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sFilesName", file_name.getText().toString()));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sImageName", image_name.getText().toString()));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sPersonName", person_name.getText().toString()));
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sPersonEmail", person_email.getText().toString()));


                    String resultServer  = getHttpPost(url,params);
                    Log.d("Entire string::", " " + resultServer);

                    /*** Default Value ***/
                    String strStatusID = "0";
                    String strError = "Cannot upload Image";

                    JSONObject c;
                    try {
                        c = new JSONObject(resultServer);
                        strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
                        strError = c.getString("Message");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    // Prepare Save Data
                    if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
                    {
                        ad.setMessage(strError);
                        ad.show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image uploaded Successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                private String getHttpPost(String url,
                        List<NameValuePair> params) {

                    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
                    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                    try {

                        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
                        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
                        if (statusCode == 200) { // Status OK
                            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                            String line;
                            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                str.append(line);
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.e("Log", "Failed to download result..");
                        }
                    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return str.toString();
                }

            });

            cancelbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override                   
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        alertDialog.dismiss();
                    }
            });
            break;
        }
    }

    //Upload
    public void startUpload(final int position) {      
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                        // Show ProgressBar
                        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        //  Status  
                        TextView status = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
                        status.setText("Uploading..");

                        new UploadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));   
                    }
                }); 
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }


    // Async Upload
    public class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        String resServer;
        int position;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            //  TODO Auto-generated method stub
            position = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);

            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int resCode = 0;
            String resMessage = "";

            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary =  "*****";

            //  File Path
            strSDPath = ImageList.get(position).toString();

            // Upload to PHP Script
            String strUrlServer = "http://10.0.2.2/res/uploadFile.php";             

            try {
                /** Check file on SD Card ***/
                File file = new File(strSDPath);
                if(!file.exists())
                {
                    resServer = "{\"StatusID\":\"0\",\"Error\":\"Please check path on SD Card\"}";
                    return null;
                }

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(strSDPath));

                URL url = new URL(strUrlServer);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);  
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(conn
                        .getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream
                .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filUpload\";filename=\""
                        + strSDPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // Read file
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Response Code and  Message
                resCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if(resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = is.read()) != -1) {
                        bos.write(read);
                    }
                    byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
                    bos.close();

                    resMessage = new String(result);
                }

                Log.d("resCode=",Integer.toString(resCode));
                Log.d("resMessage=",resMessage.toString());

                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                resServer = resMessage.toString();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Exception handling
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            statusWhenFinish(position,resServer);
        }
    }

    // when upload finish
    protected void statusWhenFinish(int position, String resServer) {

        View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

        // Show ProgressBar
        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);


        // Status
        TextView status = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
        /*** Default Value ***/
        String strStatusID = "0";
        String strMessage = "Unknow Status!";

        try {      

            JSONObject c = new JSONObject(resServer);
            strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
            strMessage = c.getString("Message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Prepare Status       
        if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
        {
            // When update Failed
            status.setText( strMessage );
            status.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            // Enabled Button again
            Button btnUpload = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
            btnUpload.setText("Already Uploaded");
            btnUpload.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            btnUpload.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            status.setText("Upload Completed.");
            status.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i believe your logic will help me,..post code what you think i should use using my above with modification which require

Comment: yes you have the only last value in your fileName variable thats why you are getting the same all the time

Comment: buddy i have posted my whole code, now you can see that above

Comment: i thik you are uploading the exact picture but only the problem with showing the pic name in dialog am i right?

Comment: you have not used your startUpload(final int position)   this method any where in your class

Comment: you did that bro :) you are great, God Bless You

Comment: sorry forgot to ask trying to call startUpload(position); method by using click on OK of AlertDialog to store images, but always getting position cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: declare position as a global variable as i declared selectedImageName

Comment: i agree with you please can you show me, i tried like this int position; but in method here, getting: public void startUpload(position) {} Multiple markers at this line
 - position cannot be resolved to a type
 - Syntax error on token "position", VariableDeclaratorId expected after 
  this token   if possible so please show me how i should use this method

Comment: yes sure i will    please declare position as a global variable as i declared selectedImageName

Comment: i tried like this int position; but in method here, getting: public void startUpload(position) {} Multiple markers at this line - position cannot be resolved to a type - Syntax error on token "position", VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token if possible so please show me how i should use this method

Comment: you have to wait for that please

Comment: sure i will do wait and i believe you will resolve this issue easily as you did earlier :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32720/discussion-between-farrukh-and-abrahim-neil)

Comment: see this question, i guess you can help me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445910/uploading-first-rows-image-not-exact-rows-which-i-have-clicked-in-a-list

Comment: hi.. please check this issue, i hope you can resolve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17445910/how-to-upload-specific-list-image-using-dialog-box

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass filenames for each of the data

```
btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
   public void onClick(View v) {                   
      // Upload
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putString("filename", fileName );
      showDialog(DIALOG_LOGIN, bundle);
   }
});
```

And then you have to change your onPrepareDialog method to following

```
@Override
 protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog, Bundle bundle) {
     super.onPrepareDialog(id, dialog, bundle);

     switch(id) {
         case DIALOG_LOGIN:
         ...
         ...
         file_name.setText(bundle.getString("filename"));
         break;
     }

 }
```

Comment: getting blank, not getting any image name