# How to upload specific List image using click on Upload button

Tags: android, android-listview

How to upload specific image to server, whenever user do click on Upload button in a List View Item Row

*Using below line to show specific Image Name in Dialog Box, whenever user do click on Upload button:*

```
 fileName=ImageList.get(position).toString().substring(strPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, strPath.length());
```

**OldUploadActivity.java:**

```
            //  btnUpload
            btnUpload = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
            btnUpload.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            btnUpload.setTag(strPath);
            btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            public void onClick(View v) {                   
                // Upload

                fileName=ImageList.get(position).toString().substring(strPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, strPath.length());

                }
            });     



    //Upload
    public void startUpload(final int position) {      
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                        // Show ProgressBar
                        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        //  Status  
                        TextView status = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
                        status.setText("Uploading..");

                        new UploadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));   
                    }
                }); 
            }
        };
        new Thread(runnable).start();
    }


    // Async Upload
    public class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        String resServer;
        int position;           

        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();               
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            //  TODO Auto-generated method stub

            int position;

            position = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
            Log.d("position::", " " + position);

            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            int resCode = 0;
            String resMessage = "";

            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary =  "*****";
            String strSDPath;

            //  File Path
            strSDPath = ImageList.get(position).toString();

            // Upload to PHP Script
            String strUrlServer = "http://10.0.2.2/res/files.php";              

            try {
                /** Check file on SD Card ***/
                File file = new File(strSDPath);
                if(!file.exists())
                {
                    resServer = "{\"StatusID\":\"0\",\"Error\":\"Please check path on SD Card\"}";
                    return null;
                }

                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(strSDPath));

                URL url = new URL(strUrlServer);
                HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);  
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

                DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(conn
                        .getOutputStream());
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                outputStream
                .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filUpload\";filename=\""
                        + strSDPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // Read file
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Response Code and  Message
                resCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                if(resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                {
                    InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                    int read = 0;
                    while ((read = is.read()) != -1) {
                        bos.write(read);
                    }
                    byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
                    bos.close();

                    resMessage = new String(result);
                }

                Log.d("resCode=",Integer.toString(resCode));
                Log.d("resMessage=",resMessage.toString());

                fileInputStream.close();
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                resServer = resMessage.toString();

            } catch (Exception ex) {
                // Exception handling
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            statusWhenFinish(position,resServer);
        }
    }

    // when upload finish
    protected void statusWhenFinish(int position, String resServer) {

        View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());

        // Show ProgressBar
        ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // Status
        TextView status = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
        /*** Default Value ***/
        String strStatusID = "0";
        String strMessage = "Unknow Status!";

        try {      
            JSONObject c = new JSONObject(resServer);
            strStatusID = c.getString("StatusID");
            strMessage = c.getString("Message");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Prepare Status       
        if(strStatusID.equals("0"))
        {
            // When update Failed
            status.setText( strMessage );
            status.setTextColor(Color.RED);

            // Enabled Button again
            Button btnUpload = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
            btnUpload.setText("Already Uploaded");
            btnUpload.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            btnUpload.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else
        {
            status.setText("Upload Completed");
            status.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
        }
    }
```

**activity_column.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ColImgPath"
android:layout_width="110dp"
android:layout_height="110dp"
/>

<ProgressBar
android:id="@+id/progressBar"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<TableLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<TableRow
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
android:id="@+id/ColImgName"
android:text="Column 1" />


</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/ColStatus"
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
android:text="Status" />

</TableRow>

<TableRow
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnUpload"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Upload" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/btnPrint"
style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Print" />


</TableRow>

</TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Use `ListView.OnItemClickedListener` instead, as that one provides you with a position of the clicked item.

Comment: Please someone help me, really struggling in such a small issue, no one has given me any suggestion or answer, i saw this first time on Stackoverflow

Comment: View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());   I think you get First data from first row always from this line,, I am not sure thn also please chk it once,, thn also if i have any idea i ll tell you.

Comment: Are you using custom list view i.e you have button inside the list view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this code:

```
        btnUpload = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnUpload);
        btnUpload.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        btnUpload.setTag(strPath);
        btnUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {                   
            // Upload

             startUpload(position);
             fileName=ImageList.get(position).toString()
            .substring(strPath.lastIndexOf('/')+1, strPath.length());

            }
        });     



//Upload
public void startUpload(final int position) {      
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    View v = lstView.getChildAt(position - lstView.getFirstVisiblePosition());
                    // Show ProgressBar
                    ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar)v.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
                    progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    //  Status  
                    TextView status = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.ColStatus);
                    status.setText("Uploading..");

                    new UploadFileAsync().execute(String.valueOf(position));   
                }
            }); 
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}


// Async Upload
public class UploadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    String resServer;
    int position;           

    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();               
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        //  TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int position;

        position = Integer.parseInt(params[0]);
        Log.d("position::", " " + position);

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        int resCode = 0;
        String resMessage = "";

        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";
        String strSDPath;

        //  File Path
        strSDPath = ImageList.get(position).toString();

        // Upload to PHP Script
        String strUrlServer = "http://10.0.2.2/res/files.php";              

        try {
            /** Check file on SD Card ***/
            File file = new File(strSDPath);
            if(!file.exists())
            {
                resServer = "{\"StatusID\":\"0\",\"Error\":\"Please check path on SD Card\"}";
                return null;
            }

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(strSDPath));

            URL url = new URL(strUrlServer);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);  
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setUseCaches(false);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(conn
                    .getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream
            .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"filUpload\";filename=\""
                    + strSDPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Response Code and  Message
            resCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            if(resCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
            {
                InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                int read = 0;
                while ((read = is.read()) != -1) {
                    bos.write(read);
                }
                byte[] result = bos.toByteArray();
                bos.close();

                resMessage = new String(result);
            }

            Log.d("resCode=",Integer.toString(resCode));
            Log.d("resMessage=",resMessage.toString());

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            resServer = resMessage.toString();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // Exception handling
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        statusWhenFinish(position,resServer);
    }
}
```