# How to know which button is click from custom list

Tags: android, toast, custom-lists

I have a custom list in which each row have one image view and one text view and two buttons.

````````````
|```````````|  text box
|Image View |
|___________|  Button1 Button2
````````````

It is the layout of one row of list.
My custom AdapterClass is..

```
public class sublist extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity context;
    private final Vector<String> shortDisJornals;
    private final Vector<String> imageId1;

    public sublist(Activity context, Vector<String> s1,
            Vector<String> imageId1) {
        super(context, R.layout.sublist, s1);
        this.context = context;
        this.shortDisJornals = s1;
        this.imageId1 = imageId1;
        Log.d("image vector", ""+imageId1);

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sublist, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewjurnals);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewJurnals);
        Button buyJurnals=(Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonjurnalsBuy);
        buyJurnals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "sdsd"+position, 3000).show();
            }
        });
        Button detailsJurnalis=(Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.buttonjrnalsDetails);
        txtTitle.setText(shortDisJornals.elementAt(position));
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
         .permitAll().build();

       StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        String image = imageId1.elementAt(position);
         try { 
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(
                 image).getContent());
          imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
               imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
               // setContentView(image);
              } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
              }catch(Exception e){}


        return rowView;


     }
}
```

Now in my main Activity -

```
lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
titleVector = new Vector<String>();
imageUrl = new Vector<String>();
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sd", 3000).show();

    }
});
```

but toast dose not show when i click the button

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

Comment: can you tell whether you want click listener for the buttons or for the lsitview rows. Its confusing and not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting an onClickListener for one of the buttons: buttonjurnalsBuy. Clicking this button should work. Just set another Listener for the other Button to handle clicks on this button.

The listener that you set in setOnItemClickListener is called if the whole row in the list is clicked.

If you set individual click listeners for some of the views and an OnItemClickListener the click listeners will be called if the user clicks one of those views. The OnItemClickListener will be called if the user clicks somewhere else in the row.

Comment: won't the imageview take focus when you click the list row. so the toast is not displayed!

Comment: If the click is not handled by one of the views in the row, the OnItemClickListener should be called.