# Always remove last item from db

Tags: android, database, list, listview

i've some issue here. While choosing listview item to remove, its work fine one the list. But while re-loading list from db, the removed list in db is always the last list. And item choosen appears again.

here the code :

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search_results_item_remove_view, null);

    list = data.get(position);

    TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item_text); // title
    ImageView remove = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.item_remove);
    remove.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.deleteContact(list.getID());
            data.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Please wait. updating list...",
                  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });        

    // Setting all values in listview
    title.setText(list.getName().toString());
    return vi;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: make sure its get deleted from the DB when you call db.deleteContact(list.getID()); or post code for db.deleteContact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use item OnClickListener :

```
public OnClickListener mOnTitleClickListener3 = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final int position = list_v
                    .getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
            list = data.get(position);
            db.deleteContact(list.getID());
            data.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

            Log.d("you are click on Ratings","you are click on Ratings");

        }
    };
```

[here is full example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654)