# Listview button click issue in android

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I'm using a list view and there is a button called "Order" in the list item. I want to show a "tick" image  when the user presses the button and hide it when the user presses the button again.

My issue is when I clicked on the button on the first item, tick image of the 4th and 8th item  is also appeared.

This is the onClickListener in the adapter,

```
    viewHolderItem.btnOrder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isSelected = shoe.isSelected();

            if(isSelected){
                viewHolderItem.ivTick.setImageDrawable(null);
                isSelected = false;
            }else{
                viewHolderItem.ivTick.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick));
                isSelected = true;
            }

            shoeList.get(position).setSelected(isSelected);
            obj.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

What is the reason for this issue?

update: This is my adapte getview method

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    final ViewHolderItem viewHolderItem;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.component_order_shoe_row,null);

        viewHolderItem = new ViewHolderItem();

        viewHolderItem.tvName = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_component_order_shoe_name);
        viewHolderItem.tvPrice = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_component_order_shoe_price);
        viewHolderItem.tvDesc = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_component_order_shoe_description);
        viewHolderItem.ivPic = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_component_order_shoe_pic);
        viewHolderItem.ivTick = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_component_order_shoe_tick);
        viewHolderItem.spinnerSize = (Spinner)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_component_order_shoe_size);
        viewHolderItem.etQty = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.et_component_order_shoe_qty);
        viewHolderItem.btnOrder = (Button)convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_component_order_shoe_order);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolderItem);

    }else{
        viewHolderItem = (ViewHolderItem)convertView.getTag();
    }

    final Shoe shoe = shoeList.get(position);
    viewHolderItem.tvName.setText(shoe.getShoeName());

    String text = String.valueOf(shoe.getPrice());
    int integerPlaces = text.indexOf('.');
    int decimalPlaces = text.length() - integerPlaces - 1;
    if(decimalPlaces==1){
        viewHolderItem.tvPrice.setText("Rs."+ text + "0");
    }else{
        viewHolderItem.tvPrice.setText("Rs."+ text);
    }
    viewHolderItem.tvDesc.setText(shoe.getDesc());

    Bitmap bmp = AppControl.convertStringToBitmap(shoe.getImg());
    viewHolderItem.ivPic.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    int smallest = shoe.getSmallestSize();
    int largest = shoe.getLargestSize();

    Integer[] arr = getSizeArray(smallest,largest);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(mContext, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arr);
    viewHolderItem.spinnerSize.setAdapter(adapter);


    viewHolderItem.btnOrder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            boolean isSelected = shoe.isSelected();

            if(isSelected){
                viewHolderItem.ivTick.setImageDrawable(null);
                isSelected = false;
            }else{
                viewHolderItem.ivTick.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick));
                isSelected = true;
            }

            shoeList.get(position).setSelected(isSelected);
            obj.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your whole adapter code?

Comment: This type of problem occur when getview method recycles.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Listview click to show image in ImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813770/listview-click-to-show-image-in-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the tag when the view is created for the first time so:

```
if(convertView==null){
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    //code

    viewHolderItem.btnOrder= (ImageButton)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);

    viewHolderItem.btnOrder.setTag(viewHolder); //set the tag for the button
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
    viewHolderItem = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

And get it inside the click listener:

```
viewHolderItem.btnOrder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         viewHolderItem = (ViewHolder) v.getTag(); //get the tag inside on click
         boolean isSelected = shoe.isSelected();

         if(isSelected){
            viewHolderItem.ivTick.setImageDrawable(null);
            isSelected = false;
         }else{
            viewHolderItem.ivTick.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick));
            isSelected = true;
         }

         shoeList.get(position).setSelected(isSelected);
         obj.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

Comment: @chathura2020 Mmh your issue is generated because the view is recycled. So setting the tag when the view is created and get it inside the view of the imageButton would be the right way..

Answer (score -1):

You should add tag to every row :

in getView mehtod :

```
viewHolderItem.setTag(viewHolderItem);
```

and add getId() method in Show class and return id

change onclick listener like :

```
viewHolderItem.btnOrder.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        boolean isSelected = shoe.isSelected();

        if(isSelected){
            viewHolderItem.ivTick.setImageDrawable(null);
            isSelected = false;
        }else{
            viewHolderItem.ivTick.setImageDrawable(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tick));
            isSelected = true;
        }

        showList(viewHolderItem.getTag()).setSelected(isSelected);
        obj.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

The problem occurs becuse when you scroll up/down, getView() is called for every row i.e. for Row 4, 5 etc.  So. the `position` value changes very frequently. so we should use `viewHolderItem.getTag()` value which will solve this problem

Comment: shoeList(viewHolderItem).setSelected(isSelected); ??? shoeList is an arraylist . viewHolderItem  is not a int.

Comment: Sorry.. use `showList(viewHolderItem.getTag()).setSelected(isSelected);`