# Setting Image inside Customer Adapter (Non Activity)

Tags: android, imageview

I have an favourite ImageButton sitting on another Imageview. This is coming properly but when I set new image accordingly inside I get two of the same image.

I am not sure where this is wrong?

here is my XML (Which has ImageView):

```
   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/grid_regular_image"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/none"
    tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/favouriteIcon"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item_image"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:visibility="invisible" />
```

And here is my Custom Apadter file: Here I am calling the image on click part too.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) 
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.emb_gridlist_items, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.favourite = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.favouriteIcon);
        holder.favourite.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    favouriteclicked = pref.getString("favourite", getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.favouritenotclicked));

    if (favouriteclicked.equalsIgnoreCase(getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.favouritenotclicked)))
    {
        holder.favourite.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.anim_alpha));
        holder.favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_starfill);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor6 = pref.edit();
        editor6.putString("favouriteclicked", getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.favouriteclicked));
        editor6.commit();
    }
    else
    {
        holder.favourite.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.anim_alpha));

        holder.favourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_stillnofill);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor6 = pref.edit();
        editor6.putString("favouriteclicked", getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.favouritenotclicked));
        editor6.commit();
    }

    holder.favourite.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v)  
        {
            favouriteclicked = pref.getString("favourite",    getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.favouriteclicked));

            ImageButton favi = (ImageButton) v;

            if (favouriteclicked.equalsIgnoreCase(getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.favouritenotclicked)))
            {
                favi.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.anim_alpha));

                favi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_starfill);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor6 = pref.edit();
                editor6.putString("favouriteclicked", getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.favouriteclicked));
                editor6.commit();
            }
            else
            {
                favi.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.anim_alpha));

                favi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_stillnofill);

                SharedPreferences.Editor editor6 = pref.edit();
                editor6.putString("favouriteclicked", getContext().getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.string.favouritenotclicked));
                editor6.commit();
            }
        }
    });
    }
```

With the above code. When I click the Favourite icon I can see two icons simultaneously. One old image and other new image.

How do I clear the old Image?

Thnaks!

Comment: This is because your view is recycled, you are not setting any tag on the View of the Imagebutton, and you are not getting any tag inside the onClick() of the ImageButton  
P.s. check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29181500/listview-button-click-issue-in-android/29181602#29181602. I think the issue is similar.

Comment: Solved it. Thanks a lot Fondesa. Though the link didn't give me much use but your logic did.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do `ImageButton favi = (ImageButton) v;`

That imageButton should already be stored in viewHolder.favourite.