# How to Implement onItemClick() for multiple ListViews separately?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am developing an app for a book, which have 13 units, each unit contain many exercises and each exercise contains many scanned images.

Now I have a Main Menu Activity, and 2 fragments, fragmentA for showing the exercises in ListView and fragmentB for showing the scanned images of exercises.

My Main Menu Activity contain 13 buttons, each button for every unit, to load that unit's exercises.

I have created ArrayLists of exercises for each unit separately, to load them into fragmentA when user tap on a specific unit.

I have created a Switch Case in the Main Menu Activity for button clicks of each unit, which loads the ArrayList of that specific unit in fragmentA in a listview.

Onbackpress it takes user back from fragmentA to Main Menu.

Now I am trying to implement OnItemClick() for clicks on ListViews which are loaded into fragmentA for each exercise of each unit.

If I set toast inside fragmentA OncreatView it assign them all of the ListViews of all the units.
But I want to do separately for each exercise of each unit i.e for all the entries in my all ArrayLists.

As am using bundle to pass the data from ArayLists into fragmentA, like this

```
 @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArrayList(LISTVIEW_DATA, unit1);
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArrayList(LISTVIEW_DATA, unit2);
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putStringArrayList(LISTVIEW_DATA,  unit3);
            break;
 default:
            break;
    }

    setListFragment(bundle);
}
private void setListFragment(Bundle arguments) {
    Fragment fragment = new ExFragment();

    if (arguments != null) {
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
    }

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
    ft.addToBackStack("");
    ft.commit();
}
```

This is my onItemClick in fragmentA.

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
```

I know its pretty basic question but am on it for hours.

Thanks

I have one fragmentA for 13 ArrayLists, showing only one at a time, and am looking for a way to assign onitemclick to all the items in 13 listviews.

Comment: I'm a little confused, can you give us some more details?

Comment: I have updated the question please do ask if u dont understand anything

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Listview click to show image in ImageView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813770/listview-click-to-show-image-in-imageview)

Comment: @DhawalSodhaParmar my question is a lot different, am trying to handle onitemclick for multiple listviews, in my case only one array is visible at a time when fragment is loaded

Comment: @leparlon can you answer it now please?

Comment: It's quite difficult to guess what are you doing in your code.
Normally you have a ListView in your first screen? and then what?

Comment: This is so confusing, I'm so curious and I can see you really need help (and by your updates you are clearly working for it). So I will start a bounty for this, please make sure to accept the answer that solves your problem or it will go to waste. Also, people will probably need more details, so provide them if you can.

Comment: @leparlon i really really appreciate ur efforts man, it was so generous of u to put the bounty on it but I actually solved the issue last day with the help of a stock member, that was so kind of u, really, i guess you can't take the bounty off now, can u?

Comment: No, but that's not a problem

Comment: Thank u so much for your honest effort, that was so kind of you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who is going through the same situation as I was, I assigned a tag named `DATA_TYPE` to each case and made `switch case` for each tag in `on create view` of fragment and solved the issue

```
  @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.button1:
        bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivityFragment.DATA_TYPE, DATA_TYPE1);
        bundle.putStringArrayList(LISTVIEW_DATA, items1);
        break;
    case R.id.button2:
        bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivityFragment.DATA_TYPE, DATA_TYPE2);
        bundle.putStringArrayList(LISTVIEW_DATA, items2);
        break;
    case R.id.button3:
        bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(MainActivityFragment.DATA_TYPE, DATA_TYPE3);
        bundle.putStringArrayList(LISTVIEW_DATA, items3);
        break;
    default:
        break;
}

setListFragment(bundle);
}
```

while `MainActivityFragment` is the name of fragment class.
Hope it helps to someone

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements 
    View.OnClickListener {

    TextView name,  summary,  publishT;
    NetworkImageView  imageView;
    Button sharesNews;

    List<NewsDataModel> highlights = new ArrayList<NewsDataModel>();
    Context ctx;

    @SuppressWarnings("SpellCheckingInspection")
    public MyViewHolder(View itemView, Context ctx, List<NewsDataModel> 
      highlights) {

        super( itemView );
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.highlights = highlights;

        name = itemView.findViewById( R.id.titlehgh );
        summary = itemView.findViewById( R.id.summaryhgh );
        publishT = itemView.findViewById( R.id.publishtH );
        imageView = itemView.findViewById( R.id.thumbnailhgh );

        itemView.setOnClickListener( this );

        sharesNews = itemView.findViewById( R.id.shares );

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        int position = getAdapterPosition();
        NewsDataModel newsDataModel = this.highlights.get( position );
        Intent intent = new Intent ( this.ctx, NewsDetailsActivity.class );

        intent.putExtra( "id", newsDataModel.getId() );
        this.ctx.startActivity( intent );
    }
}
```