# How to set the data from activity to fragment listview in android?

Tags: android

Explanation:
           I have a button in my fragment.When i press this button it's called an activity.In activity, i want to fill some details and save this detail and after saved details my activity is closed and goes to the fragment.Inside the fragment i have listview.In listview i want to display all the details which i early added from my activity. E.g. alarm in your mobile phone.

Structure:

```
     Fragment->activity
     activity->fragment->display details into the listview.
```

How can i manage this.

Please help me to solve out.

Comment: Once I was in the same situation as you, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34684598/how-to-implement-onitemclick-for-multiple-listviews-separately)

Comment: Understand my question completely.

Comment: Did you tried `startActivityForResult()`?