# Color icon and text in Android Studio

Tags: android, mobile-application

how to make the color of text and icon in List View automatically based on gender? 
Example blue for boys and pink for girl.

[this sample of the interface. the list names get from database in server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4xw6.png)

```
       @Override
            public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                // Get ImageView
                ImageView ivGender = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivGender);

                // Check if it is male or female and set the image
                if (GetAll.get(position).getgender().equals('M')){
                    ivGender.setImageResource(R.drawable.roundM);
                }else{
                    ivGender.setImageResource(R.drawable.roundF);
                }

                return convertView;
            }
```

This is my coding for icon. 
How to to change the text color?

Comment: please show your code

Comment: I edit my question and put some interface

Comment: Design two custom list-view items with blue and pink color. Keep the values in shared prefs and later check for boy/ girl condition. Accordingly show the list-view.

Comment: how about the coding?

Comment: what text? You only have an ImageView

Comment: sorry.. I miss some coding there

Comment: // Check if it is male or female and set the image and colour of text name
        if (nameArrayList.get(position).equals("M")){
                ivGender.setImageResource(R.drawable.roundm);
                tvNama.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0f64cb"));

        }

        else {
                ivGender.setImageResource(R.drawable.roundf);
                tvNama.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#fa00c3"));
        }

            return convertView;

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **holder in listiview** to set different property based on your sorting here it is gender with many records in your list.

This is your model class,

```
ArrayList<YourModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Static list class used in getView() method,

```
static class ListContent {

        ImageView ivGender;

    }
```

This way you can

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        final ListContent holder;
                        View v = convertView;
                        if (v == null) {
                            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_pvs_list_item, parent, false);
                            holder = new ListContent();             
                            holder.ivGender = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivGender);
                            v.setTag(holder);
                        } else {
                            holder = (ListContent) v.getTag();
                        }       
                        YourModel ym = list.get(position);  //your model class and arraylist declared above
                        if(ym.getgender().equalsIgnoreCase("M")){  
                           holder.ivGender.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundM));
                        else{      
                            holder.ivGender.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.roundM));
                        }
                        }
                        return v;
                    }
```

Check [ImageView in List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/2826147) for more description.

Hope this helps.

Comment: ListContent is it your class name?

Comment: // Check if it is male or female and set the image and colour of text name
        if (nameArrayList.get(position).equals("M")){
                ivGender.setImageResource(R.drawable.roundm);
                tvNama.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0f64cb"));

        }

        else {
                ivGender.setImageResource(R.drawable.roundf);
                tvNama.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#fa00c3"));
        }

            return convertView;

Comment: yes, that is done in my answer ---  YourModel ym = list.get(position); if(ym.getgender().equalsIgnoreCase("M")){
                ivGender.setImageResource(R.drawable.roundM);
            }else{
                ivGender.setImageResource(R.drawable.roundF);
            }

Comment: I just can view one color. Why it's being like this?