# How To Set OnClickListener On Different Buttons Inside a ListVeiw?

Tags: android, listview, listadapter, clickable, custom-lists

These are two OnClickListeners in the getView method of my ListView Adapter:

```
    icon_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            icon_play.setTag("play");
        }
    });

    icon_download.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            v.setTag("download");
        }
    });
```

I'm going to set OnClickListener on these two buttons in MainActivity. so I want to know what is the value of getTag() by using Toast.

```
    lst_video.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), position + "\n\n" + view.getTag() + "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

But it doesn't work. How can I understand which button has been clicked?
I have some video URL's and I want to play each one has been clicked, in a VideoView in MainActivity.

Comment: post your full adapter!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12813906/1168654

Comment: what Dhawal wants to say with the link is, that You should follow a viewholder pattern. ListViews are recycled, wich brings some benefits but also some disadvantages. With a viewholder pattern like shown in that link, You will have success....

Answer (score 1):

you have to use you holder object to use button .

try this

```
holder.icon_play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        icon_play.setTag("play");
    }
});
```