# Android click listView to expand ImageView

Tags: android, image, listview

I have a listview with a textview and imageview in each row, and am trying to figure out how to enlarge my images when clicking on them. The user takes an image from their gallery and stores them in a database with a name. They are maps of resorts/hotels for the purpose of delivering. 
This is how everything is laid out:

[image]

I'm trying to get my app to where I can click on an ImageView, or simply just the listview itself, and have the image enlarged in the center of the screen. If not enlarged in the center of the screen, I wouldn't even mind opening the enlarged image in a new activity. Either way is fine, I would just like to be able to read the maps, so doing something with pinch-to-zoom would be great! I get the images from the user's gallery and store them in a list, and ask them for a name for the hotel/resort. Then I save the information to a database and display it in a listview. I crop the images down to fit them in the listview as thumbnails, but I would like to expand them back out upon being clicked for easy readability. Any help would be greatly appreciated! My goal is to have it look like the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813770/listview-click-to-show-image-in-imageview) question, but couldn't figure out how to optimize it into my code.

My adapter class is as follows:

```
public class dataAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Hotel> {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<Hotel> mHotel;

    public dataAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Hotel> hotel)
    {
        super(context, R.layout.listhotels, hotel);
        this.context = context;
        this.mHotel = hotel;
    }

    public class Holder
    {
        TextView nameFV;
        ImageView pic;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        Hotel data = getItem(position);

        Holder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null)
        {
            viewHolder = new Holder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listhotels, parent, false);

            viewHolder.nameFV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewer);
            viewHolder.pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.nameFV.setText(data.getFName());
        viewHolder.pic.setImageBitmap(convertToBitmap(data.getImage()));

        return convertView;
    }

    private Bitmap convertToBitmap(byte[] b)
    {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(b, 0, b.length);
    }
}
```

My code to display the list of hotels:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.display_hotels);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);

    db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic);
    fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);

    final ArrayList<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<>(db.getAllHotels());

    data = new dataAdapter(this, hotels);

    data.sort(new Comparator<Hotel>()
    {
        @Override
        public int compare(Hotel arg0, Hotel arg1)
        {
            return arg0.getFName().compareTo(arg1.getFName());
        }
    });

    data.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv.setAdapter(data);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), display_full_image.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

And my main activity:

```
public class MapsMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText fname;
    private ImageView pic;
    private DatabaseHandler db;
    private String f_name;
    private ListView lv;
    private dataAdapter data;
    private Hotel dataModel;
    private Bitmap bp;
    private byte[] photo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_main);

        db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list1);
        pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pic);
        fname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    }

    public void buttonClicked(View v)
    {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch(id)
        {
            case R.id.save:
                if (fname.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name edit text is empty, Enter name", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    addHotel();
                }
                break;

            case R.id.display:
                showRecords();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), display_hotels.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.pic:
                selectImage();
                break;
        }
    }

    public void selectImage()
    {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 2);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        switch(requestCode)
        {
            case 2:
                if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
                {
                    Uri chosenImage = data.getData();

                    if(chosenImage != null)
                    {
                        bp = decodeUri(chosenImage, 400);
                        pic.setImageBitmap(bp);
                    }
                }
        }
    }

    protected Bitmap decodeUri(Uri selectedImage, int REQUIRED_SIZE)
    {
        try
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o);

            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true)
            {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                {
                    break;
                }
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImage), null, o2);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private byte[] profileImage(Bitmap b)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos);
        return bos.toByteArray();
    }

    private void getValues()
    {
        f_name = fname.getText().toString();
        photo = profileImage(bp);
    }

    private void addHotel()
    {
        getValues();

        db.addHotels(new Hotel(f_name, photo));
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private void showRecords()
    {
        final ArrayList<Hotel> hotels = new ArrayList<>(db.getAllHotels());

        data = new dataAdapter(this, hotels);
        data.notifyDataSetChanged();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                dataModel = hotels.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(dataModel.getID()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me. I would greatly appreciate it. This is for a final project for my Mobile App Development class that is due in 2 days, and I'm really close to finishing it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I dont understand where you have problems with a task that is pretty common and for which you can find many examples in the internet. In short you display a thumbnail of your image in an item of the listview. For full page you use the full image. You posted too much code. I did not even look at it.

Comment: you just wanted to show enlarged imageview with the selected image,when clicked on the image of your listItem , is that right?

Comment: @ankit purwar Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: ok, lemme try something

Comment: @AnthonyBoley to increase/decrease the size of imageView just change the values passed in layoutParams();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this getView()

```
    @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
            {
                Hotel data = getItem(position);

                Holder viewHolder;

                if (convertView == null)
                {
                    viewHolder = new Holder();
                    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listhotels, parent, false);

                    viewHolder.nameFV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewer);
                    viewHolder.pic = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgView);

                    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                }
                else
                {
                    viewHolder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
                }

                viewHolder.nameFV.setText(data.getFName());
                viewHolder.pic.setImageBitmap(convertToBitmap(data.getImage()));
        viewHolder.pic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Dialog settingsDialog = new Dialog(context);
                        settingsDialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(500, 500);
                        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
                        ImageView iv = new ImageView(context);
                        iv.setLayoutParams(lp);
                        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.img3);
//use in your case iv.setImageBitmap(convertToBitmap(data.getImage())); 
                        settingsDialog.addContentView(iv,lp);
                        settingsDialog.show();

                    }
                });

                return convertView;
            }
```

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thank you so much for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

just pass the imgeData as extra in intent when you start new Activity to display full image. and in FullImageActivit getIntent extra to get the image data and display it in an imageView.
and if you want to enable pinch zoom there a librabry to handle it
[check this](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)